# how vtk do th zoom for jpeg reader and dicom reader

Tags: c++, zooming, jpeg, vtk, dicom

This is an example of a code of vtk to read a jpeg image http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/JPEGReader  or dicom file http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadDICOM ,
when I run these projects, i can zomm the image with the right button of the mouse
however, in the code there is nothing in a direct relation with zoom or something like this, so there is something inside the classes
can anyone tell me how vtk can do this zoom because i need it in another project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, certainly there is code inside the other classes. vtkRenderWindow, vtkRenderWindowInteractor, and vtkRenderer are all referenced by that sample. You can trace down the zooming code through those. https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/tree/master/Rendering/Core